# C close STDOUT running forever

Tags: c, pipe, infinite-loop

I am writing some C code that involves the use of pipes.  To make a child process use my pipe instead of STDOUT for output, I used the following lines:

```
    close(STDOUT);
    dup2(leftup[1], STDOUT);
```

However, it seems to go into some sort of infinite loop or hang on those lines.  When I get rid of `close`, it hangs on `dup2`.

Curiously, the same idea works in the immediately preceding line for STDIN:

```
close(STDIN);
dup2(leftdown[0], STDIN);
```

What could be causing this behavior?

Edit:  Just to be clear...

```
#define STDIN   0
#define STDOUT  1
```

Edit 2:  Here is a stripped-down example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

#define STDIN   0
#define STDOUT  1

main(){
    pid_t child1 = 0;
    int leftdown[2];
    if (pipe(leftdown) != 0)
        printf("ERROR");
    int leftup[2];
    if (pipe(leftup) != 0)
        printf("ERROR");

    printf("MADE PIPES");

    child1 = fork();
    if (child1 == 0){
        close(STDOUT);
        printf("TEST 1");
        dup2(leftup[1], STDOUT);
        printf("TEST 2");
        exit(0);
    }
    return(0);  
}
```

The `"TEST 1"` line is never reached.  The only output is `"MADE PIPES"`.

Comment: Just to be even clearer: there's already `STDIN_FILENO` et al. Don't reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a *minimum,* you should ensure that the `dup2` function returns the new file descriptor rather than `-1`.

There's always a possibility that it will give you an error (for example, if the `pipe()` call failed previously). In addition, be absolutely certain that you're using the right indexes (0 and 1) - I've been bitten by that before and it depends on whether you're in the parent or child process.

---

Based on your edit, I'm not the least bit surprised that `MADE PIPES` is the last thing printed.

When you try to print `TEST 1`, you have already closed the `STDOUT` descriptor so that will go nowhere.

When you try to print `TEST 2`, you have `dup`ed the `STDOUT` descriptor so that will go to the parent but your parent doesn't read it.

If you change your forking code to:

```
child1 = fork();
if (child1 == 0){
    int count;
    close(STDOUT);
    count = printf("TEST 1\n");
    dup2(leftup[1], STDOUT);
    printf("TEST 2 (%d)\n", count);
    exit(0);
} else {
    char buff[80];
    read (leftup[0], buff, 80);
    printf ("%s\n", buff);
    sleep (2);
}
```

you'll see that the `TEST 2 (-1)` line is output by the parent because it read it via the pipe. The `-1` in there is the return code from the `printf` you attempted in the child after you closed the `STDOUT` descriptor (but before you `dup`ed it), meaning that it failed.

From `ISO C11 7.20.6.3 The printf function`:

> The `printf` function returns the number of characters transmitted, or a negative value if an output or encoding error occurred.

Comment: Nothing is returned because of the snag I described.  The error handling code exists, but I trimmed it out to keep things as simple as possible.

Comment: @Andrew Latham, sorry does it hang when you take out the error handling code?

Comment: @AndrewLatham, what are the values of leftup[1] and leftdown[0]? Were these created with a `pipe()` call? Are you in the parent or child process when you attempt the `dup2()` call?

Comment: This is in a child process - they were created with a pipe call.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple thing to mention,

When you use fork, it causes almost a complete copy of parent process. That also includes the buffer that is set up for `stdout` standard output stream as well. The `stdout` stream will hold the data till buffer is full or explicitly requested to flush the data from buffer/stream. Now because of this , now you have `"MADE PIPES"` sitting in buffer. When you close the `STDOUT` fd and use `printf` for writing data out to terminal, it does nothing but transfers your `"TEST 1"` and `"TEST 2"` into the `stdout` buffer and doesn't cause any error or crash (due to enough buffer). Thus even after duplicating `pipe` fd on `STDOUT`, due to buffered output `printf` hasn't even touched pipe write end. Most important, please use only one set of APIs i.e. either *NIX or standard C lib functions. Make sure you understand the libraries well, as they often play tricks for some sort of optimization.

Now, another thing to mention, make sure that you close the appropriate ends of pipe in appropriate process. Meaning that if say, pipe-1 is used to communicate from parent to child then make sure that you close the read end in parent and write end in child. Otherwise, your program may hung, due to reference counts associated with file descriptors you may think that closing read end in child means pipe-read end is closed. But as when you don't close the read end in parent, then you have extra reference count for read end of pipe and ultimately the pipe will never close.

There are many other things about your coding style, better you should get hold on it :)
Sooner you learn it better it will save your time. :)

Error checking is absolutely important, use at least assert to ensure that your assumptions are correct.

While using `printf` statements to log the error or as method of debugging and you are changing terminal FD's `(STDOUT / STDIN / STDERR)` its better you open a log file with `*NIX` open and write errors/ log entries to it.

At last, using `strace` utility will be a great help for you. This utility will allow you to track the system calls executed while executing your code. It is very straight forward and simple. You can even attach this to executing process, provided you have right permissions.